# Excel VBA, check for existing value with loop

Tags: excel, vba

i have a 70 names with phone numbers, how can i check with For or if else statement or both if there is phone number which is duplicating and remove the number. Thanks in advance!

```
Sub GenerateNames()
Dim ssheet1 As Worksheet
Dim rngen As Worksheet
Dim rnsheet As Worksheet

Dim i As Integer, intValueToFind As Integer
intValueToFind = 12345

Set ssheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rngen = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RnGen")
Set rnsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RandomNames")

rngen.Range("A3:A70").Copy rnsheet.Range("A3:A70")
ssheet1.Range("B3:B70").Copy rnsheet.Range("B3:B70")


For b = 1 To 70
    If Cells(b, 2).Value = intValueToFind Then
        MsgBox ("Found value on row " & i)
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next b

MsgBox ("Value not found in the range!")
End Sub
```

Comment: use dictionary. https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for duplicate phone numbers:

```
Public Sub CheckForDupes()
    For b = 1 To 70
        For c = b + 1 To 70
            If Cells(b, 2).Value = Cells(c, 2).Value Then
                MsgBox ("Rows " & b & " and " & c & "are duplicates.")
            End If
        Next c
    Next b
End Sub
```